# Getting [Object HTMLInputElement] error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, string

looping through a json encoded output for a Month Year value, and trying to convert it a month number before passing it to next step in code ...

```
... foreach loop
    var month_number = null;
    var dateOf = JSON.stringify(v.date);
    if(dateOf.indexOf("January")>-1){month_number=1}else
    if(dateOf.indexOf("February")>-1){month_number=2}else
    if(dateOf.indexOf("March")>-1){month_number=3}
  });

  htmlStr += '<input type="hidden" id="month_number" value="' + month_number + '" />';
```

returning [Object HTMLInputElement] for month_number ... everything else is working ...

Comment: Provide some examples of v.date

Comment: Seems incomplete. Where is your starting left brace? Where is your final 'else'{} statement? (it can be a null function). Where is your count terminator?

Answer (score 1):

Without an example of v.date I can only speculate.

If a v.date is something like "January 2016", You don't need to stringify it. Just do this:

```
var vDate = new Date(v.date);
var month_number = vDate.getMonth() + 1; 
// months in JavaScript are 0-based so you need to add 1 to the value
```

No need for if/else to check for every month

Comment: Thanks for the info! Functional and way more efficient this way; awesome ...